# Is the opposite of the category of $\kappa$-Lindelöf Hausdorff spaces locally presentable?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, large-cardinals

[Gelfand duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation) tells us that the category of compact Hausdorff spaces (with continuous maps as morphisms) is contravariantly equivalent to the category of commutative, unital $C^\ast$-algebras (with $\ast$-algebra maps over $\mathbb C$ as morphisms). The latter category can be defined in $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ and is easily seen to be [locally presentable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category), and in particular it is complete and cocomplete.

Recall that a topological space $X$ is called *$\kappa$-Lindelöf* (or *$\kappa$-compact*) if every open cover of $X$ admits a subcover of cardinality $<\kappa$. So compact = $\aleph_0$-Lindelöf.

**Question 1:**
Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal. Is the opposite of the category of $\kappa$-Lindelöf Hausdorff spaces complete and cocomplete?

**Question 2:**
Is it locally presentable? If so, is there a reasonable "algebraic" presentation of the category?

**Notes:**

- Tychonoff's theorem is what tells us that the category of compact Hausdorff spaces has products / that the category of commutative unital $C^\ast$-algebras has coproducts. The analog of Tychonoff's theorem for $\kappa$-Lindelöf spaces (and I believe equivalently for $\kappa$-Lindelöf Hausdorff spaces) if and only if $\kappa$  is a [strongly compact cardinal](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Strongly_compact). So the above questions trivially have negative answers unless $\kappa$ is strongly compact. Thus we should assume in the above that $\kappa$ is a strongly compact cardinal, and we are squarely in the realm of studying large cardinals.
- Gelfand duality can be thought of as being analogous to the duality between affine schemes and commutative rings, or to Stone duality between profinite sets  -- a "geometric" category is dual to a category which is "algebraic", and hence locally presentable.

Comment: How exactly does the fact that κ-Lindelöf spaces are not closed under products in topological spaces imply that the category of κ-Lindelöf spaces is not locally presentable?

Comment: Exactly. The inclusion functor doesn't have to be product-preserving. Anyway, very interesting question.